DG-Algebra structure on initial ideal of an ideal
I have started working on the DG-Algebra structure on the graded resolution on ideal. I need help with the following.
Let $I$ be a graded ideal in a polynomial ring $S=\mathbb{K}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, where $\mathbb{K}$ is a field. Let $(\mathbf{A},d)$ be a graded resolution of the $S$-module $S/I$ and let $A_0=S$. Suppose $(\mathbf{A},d,\star)$ is a  DG-algebra.
Now, let $\mathrm{in}_<(I)$ be the initial ideal of the ideal $I$ with respect to some monomial ordering. Can we define any graded resolution on $S/\mathrm{in}_<(I)$ such that it has a DG-algebra structure using the DG-algebra structure of $(\mathbf{A},d,\star)$?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
